# Using Otto Event Bus to pass data between RecyclerViews

Tags: android, otto

I have 2 Recyclerviews inside 2 different Fragments contained in a ViewPager. When a card in my RecyclerviewA is clicked I would like to pass the respective object over to RecyclerviewB currently I have an onClick in RecyclerView with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHold holder, int position) {

    holder.nameTextView.setText(list.get(position).getString("name"));
    holder.addressTextView.setText(list.get(position).getString("fromAddress"));

    final int pos = position;
    holder.acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        ApplicationClass.bus.post(list.get(pos));

        }
    });
```

In RecyclerViewB I have

```
    public PickupListAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> ddList) {
    this.ddList = ddList;
    this.mContext = context;
    ApplicationClass.bus.register(mContext);
}

@Subscribe
public void answerAvailable(ParseObject object) {
    ddList.add(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Inside my Application Class I have:

```
public static Bus bus;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
          bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);


}
```

The "answerAvailable" method is not called. What is currently incorrect regarding my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I can see only one change from my working code. Can you try changing this:

```
 bus= new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
```